# Select my own thoughts alongwith friends thoughts

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables

```
members (id, fname, lname,...)
my_connections(id, member_id, connection_id, approved, ...`)
my_thoughts(id, member_id, thought, shared)`
```

my query

```
$sql = "
        SELECT mc.* , cp.`id` AS cp_id, cp.*,  m.* 
        FROM `my_connections` mc
        LEFT JOIN `my_thoughts` cp ON mc.`connection_id` = cp.`member_id`  
        LEFT JOIN `members` m ON m.`id` = mc.`connection_id` 
        WHERE mc.`member_id` = '".$member_id."'
        AND mc.`approved` = 1
        AND cp.`shared` = 1
        ORDER BY cp.`date_added` DESC
";
```

I get all my connections thoughts, how do I include my thoughts aswell . I tried another join where thoughts.member_id = $member_id, but it assigns my thoughts to my connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably more than one way to accomplish this, but how about using two separate queries and combining their results into one grid using UNION? In order to do that, both of your queries must select the same columns.

For example, something like this (edited):

```
SET @my_id = 1;

SELECT * FROM (
SELECT m.fname, m.lname, t.thought FROM members m
JOIN thoughts t on t.memberID = m.id
WHERE m.id = @my_id

UNION

SELECT m2.fname, m2.lname, t.thought FROM members m
JOIN connections c on c.memberID =m.ID
JOIN members m2 on m2.ID = c.connectionID
JOIN thoughts t on t.memberID = m2.ID
WHERE m.ID = @my_id

) tmp

ORDER BY tmp.lname ASC;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/405b2/17

Comment: hmm that seems to have worked...but now the ORDER BY wont work

Comment: am I suppose to call ORDER by on both queries or just at the end (which I do and it throws an unidentified column error)

Comment: Wrap the entire two queries in parens, then do an outer SELECT * FROM.. and do ORDER BY at the end. I updated our SQL Fiddle example to clarify what I mean: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/405b2/17